# How to set a handle in nouislider-react?

Tags: reactjs, nouislider

I am having trouble to set the handle of noUiSlider.
This is what I have at the moment.

```
const SearchOptionRange: React.FC<SearchOptionRangeProps> = props => {

  const [lowValue, setLowValue] = useState(props.start);
  const [highValue, setHighValue] = useState(props.end);

  const handleLow = (event: any) => {
    setLowValue(event.target.value);
  }

  const handleHigh = (event: any) => {
    setHighValue(event.target.value);

  }

  const updateValues = (value: any) => {
    setLowValue(Number(value[0]));
    setHighValue(Number(value[1]));
  };

  return (
        <div className={props.name}>
          <div className="option-name">{props.name}</div>
          <Nouislider
            start={[props.start, props.end]}
            connect={true}
            range={{
              min: props.start,
              max: props.end
            }}
            step={props.step}
            onUpdate={ (value) => updateValues(value) }
          />
          <div className="inputs">
            <input type="text" value={lowValue} onChange={ (event) => handleLow(event)}></input>
            <input type="text" value={highValue} onChange={ (event) => handleHigh(event)}></input>
          </div>
        </div>
  );
};
```

And my component is called out like this.

```
<SearchOptionRange name="price" start={300} end={25000} step={50}></SearchOptionRange>
```

The aim is to update the slider when I am inputting values into inputs. It works vice versa (slider dragging updates input values).

[How it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRtF5.png)

I just can't figure it out how I could update the slider when typing in the input. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

here is your answer : https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-visvesvaraya-xdy1w

when you type a number in each input the value of the slider gets updated and handler moves around.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Haven't tried it out yet but is there some way to improve the slider behaviour as well? At the moment if you try to slide it then it lags. It's because of the constant updating that is going on but it would be nice to smooth it out.

Comment: yes i did it. https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-visvesvaraya-xdy1w
i prevent sync updated by using onChange instead of onSlide Event

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I am still aiming for the constant update in the inputs but without lagging. Still not sure how to do it but have to reduce the updates somehow. Is there a possibility in nouislider-react to set a value on a slider? Because if the start property of slider is updating constantly then it starts lagging. 
There is a possiblity to set handle values in pureJS (https://refreshless.com/nouislider/slider-read-write/#section-setting) but I haven't managed to get it working in React.

Comment: But it's not constantly updating the values in the input either. I would like to show what is the value in the input as well. So it should update constantly (showing the current value of the slider handle).